Intuitive Understanding of d1 in Black-Scholes
I am reading about the derivation of Black-Scholes using Future prices. I understand the mathematical steps of the derivation, which starts by separating it into the difference of two integrals,
the first of which is the integration of F_T * p(F_T) from K to infinity, with F_T being the future price at expiry T,K being the strike, and p being the probability of price F_T at time T. The second of which is K times the integral of p(F_T) from K to infinity.
This second integral simplifies to giving a d_2 term which stems from the Z-score of K on this log normal distribution of F_T (negated to represent P(F_T >= K)). I intuitively understand this concept, as this directly represents the total probability that P(F_T >= K) which is multiplied by K, to represent the expected strike payment.
I am struggling to intuitively understand the d_1 term, as this is representing the Z-score of K on a log-normal distribution with opposite mean (1/2 * sigma * T^2), rather than -(1/2 * sigma * T^2). I can see how mathematically the first integral simplifies to F_0 * cdf(d_1), but i cannot understand intuitively how this distribution's cdf multiplied by F_0 equates to the integration of F_T * p(F_T) from K to infinity. Is there an intuitive way to understand this or is this just a mathematical convenience?
